# GXT HtmlEditor - How to retrieve the text?

Tags: gxt

Looking for an example of the ext-GWT / GXT HTMLEditor, especially the part where you retrieve the user's entry.

Thanks
C

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is as simple as this:

```
FormPanel formPanel = new FormPanel();    
HtmlEditor htmlEditor = new HtmlEditor();
formPanel.add(htmlEditor);
String html = htmlEditor.getValue();
```

i.e. getValue returns the user's entry.